# How to dismiss custom popup window

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, popupwindow, dismiss

I face a problem with pop-up window and drag and drop. I would like to dismiss the popup window and show a new one while I dragging my view to another view. I can create a new popup but can not dismiss the old one. How can I solve this problem? That creates a new one always.

That calls components to dismiss method can but not dismiss it.

```
`
class SubstitutionPopUpComponent @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : PopupWindow(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    val binding: ComponentPlayerSubstitutionPopupBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context),
        R.layout.component_player_substitution_popup,
        null,
        false
    )

fun createPopup(
    view: View,
    playerInName: String,
    playerOutName: String,
): PopupWindow {
    binding.apply {
        this.playerInName = playerInName
        this.playerOutName = playerOutName
    }
    val x = view.getScreenLocation()[0]
    val y = view.getScreenLocation()[1]

    return PopupWindow(
        binding.root,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ).apply {
        isOutsideTouchable = true
        isFocusable = true
        elevation = 10f
        setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x + view.width, y)
    }
}

fun dismissPopup() {
    dismiss()
}
```

}`

```
internal class MyDragListener(ctx: Context, popUpComponent: SubstitutionPopUpComponent?) :
        OnDragListener {
        val context = ctx
        val substitutionPopUpComponent = popUpComponent
        override fun onDrag(target: View, event: DragEvent): Boolean {
            when (event.action) {
                DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                    if (substitutionPopUpComponent.isNotNull()) {
                        substitutionPopUpComponent?.dismissPopup()
                    }

                    val dragged = event.localState as View
                    val oldPlayer = dragged.parent as ViewGroup
                    val newPlayer = target.parent as ViewGroup

                    when {
                        (oldPlayer as SquadPlayerComponent).binding.player != null -> {
                            when ((newPlayer as SquadPlayerComponent).playerPosition) {
                                oldPlayer.playerPosition -> {
                                    if (oldPlayer.binding.player != null && newPlayer.binding.player != null) {
                                        Utils.swapPlayers(
                                            oldPlayer.binding.player!!,
                                            newPlayer.binding.player!!,
                                            oldPlayer.isSubPlayer,
                                            newPlayer.isSubPlayer,
                                            newPlayer.playerPosition.toString()
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                    val dragged = event.localState as View
                    val oldPlayer = dragged.parent as ViewGroup
                    val newPlayer = target.parent as ViewGroup

                    substitutionPopUpComponent?.apply {
                        createPopup(oldPlayer,
                            (newPlayer as SquadPlayerComponent).binding.player?.name.toString(),
                            (oldPlayer as SquadPlayerComponent).binding.player?.name.toString()
                        )
                    }
                }

                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                    if (substitutionPopUpComponent.isNotNull()) {
                        substitutionPopUpComponent?.dismissPopup()
                    }
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve a problem ?

Comment: Yes @ArtemViter I have changed draglistener to this and problem solved.

internal class MyDragListener(private var substitutionPopUp: PopupWindow?) :
        OnDragListener {

Answer (score 0):

Looks like since android api level 24 the view has method [updateDragShadow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#updateDragShadow(android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder)) which updates the drag shadow for the ongoing drag and drop operation. i.e. you can pass new instance of DragShadowBuilder which will be transparent or nothing draw to `target.updateDragShadow(emptyDragShadowBuilder)` from your DragListener and you will can get what you want.

I am not sure but i think you can do same thing without updateDragShadow:
When you call to [startDragAndDrop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#startDragAndDrop(android.content.ClipData,%20android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) method you can pass instance of DragShadowBuilder with your view object. Consider the implementation of
DragShadowBuilder.onDrawShadow:

```
public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
            final View view = mView.get();
            if (view != null) {
                view.draw(canvas);
            } else {
                Log.e(View.VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Asked to draw drag shadow but no view");
            }
        }
```

look like you can change view passed to DragShadowBuilder and call invalidate on this view. Or you can extend DragShadowBuilder which will cache canvas and then after changing a view just call onDrawShadow() which will use cached canvas:

```
public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
            mCanvas = canvas;
            onDrawShadow();
        }

public void onDrawShadow() {
            final View view = mView.get();
            if (view != null && mCanvas != null) {
                view.draw(mCanvas);
            } else {
                Log.e(View.VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Asked to draw drag shadow but no view");
            }
        }
```